# Issues with KeyStrokes Inside OnCollisionEnter2D

Tags: c#, methods, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to game that whenever a PREFAB file hits a invisible 2-D collider, when the user presses a key, the picture will be destroyed. I sorted out the prefab clone problem, but it seems the method of void OnCollisionEnter2D doesn't seem to recognize the KeyStroke command.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class A2 : MonoBehaviour {

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col)
{
    if(col.gameObject.name == "NeatPrefab(Clone)")
    {
        print ("works!");
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C)) {

            //if object hits collider, then you can delete!
        }
    }

}
```

}

Do I need to create a new method or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `Input.GetKey` instead of `Input.GetKeyDown`, and if the user is pressing the key while the collision happens, it should be detected.

Your code right now would only work if the user pressed the key at the exact moment when the collision happens - the timing is very tricky and I doubt that it is the intended behavior.